# Hamburger Button in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I want to fix the classic bootstrap style hamburger button on my navbar, like the one that appears as a toggle button when the screen size gets sufficiently small.

Anyways, how can I display the button as is, without having to implement it through the navbar-toggle class?

EDIT: Here is the button I have:

```
<div>
    <div class="center">
        <button type="button" class="btn">☰</button>
    </div>
</div>   



body {
background: #222;
```

}

```
.center {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #222;
  border: 1px solid #3A3A3A;
  color: #D3D3D3;
  width: 42px;
  margin-left: 42px;
  font-size: 23px;
  height: 34px;
  transition: color 0.45s;
  transition: border 0.45s;
}

button.btn:hover {
  color: #2978E0;
  border: 1px solid #61A5FF;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rstty1ye/

Using a UTF-8 character was mentioned on tutsplus.com
It's not my original finding or idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

Created a custom button and used an UTF-8 character: Trigram for Heaven for the bars.

Comment: Can you share your solution in the answer?

Comment: Done. It's a pretty ordinary button, just that instead of using the usual method of creating 3 rectangles and giving a border radius, here we use a UTF-8 character that looks similar.